# Django Rest Framework Module Not Found Error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I made sure that every step was followed correctly but this happened and I don't know how to solve this.

```
**ERROR:**
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000017F5090E620>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Chrisannesuuuu\etona\etona\etona\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    import etona.quickstart.views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'etona.quickstart'
```

[image: file structure]

**urls.py**

```
    from django.urls import include, path
    from rest_framework import routers
    import etona.quickstart.views


    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register(r'users', etona.quickstart.views.UserViewSet)
    router.register(r'groups', etona.quickstart.views.GroupViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from etona.quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
    from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')
```

when typing python manage.py runserver, the error above appeared. How can i fix it? help please. Im trying to run the djangorestframework and connect it to angular to have a simple registration , so i followed the instructions on this website https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/ but it doesn't seem to work on me. Maybe I missed something. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Use `import quickstart.views` istead of `import etona.quickstart.views`

Comment: Hi, you probably missed the trailing dot when creating the project since the manage.py file doesn't look in the right place. You should not move files around and/or ensure you have the same layout as the one shown in the quick start.

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan Thank you so much. It is now working. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `quickstart.views` instead of `import etona.quickstart.views` in `urls.py` and `views.py`

Answer (score 1):

use in **views.py** change this line

`from etona.quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer`

**to**

`from quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer`

**urls.py** -from

`etona.quickstart import views`

**to**

`from quickstart import views`